# Задать отступы для динамического элемента select

Tags: html, css

Необходимо чтобы элемент `select` занимал всю ширину блока и имел отступы `margin: 10px 15px 0 15px;`.

Стиль с отступами не срабатывает справа, растягивается на всю ширину глобального родительского блока у которого нет отступов. Если добавить этот селект в `div` с необходимыми паддингами, то все отлично работает. Но так сделать нельзя, т.к. селект динамический и создается из функции js.

Как добавить динамическому селекту отступы `margin` и при этом оставить его независимым от других элементов ?

[Разметка и стили](https://jsfiddle.net/lilubanana/xqe4cb0m/)

```
<select>
  <option value="0">text</option>
  <option value="571">text</option>
</select>


select {
width: 100%;
height: 35px;
margin: 10px 15px 0 15px;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

**UPD**

Ошиблась в стиле указанном в вопросе. Но в проекте ошибки нет. Стили указаны верно, но не работает.

Comment: У вас сайт фиксированный или адаптивный/резиновый?

Comment: это мобильное приложение на js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение состоит в том что б добавлять вместе с select div с класом. А отступ будет работать с padding;

Нужно отказаться от margin потому что:

> http://htmlbook.ru/css/box-sizing

Свойство "box-sizing" на margin не действует. 
Его смена учитывает: padding c border а margin пропускает.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bearwolf/sjkh3yqp/)

```js
create();

function create() {
 var select = "<div class='place'><select><option value='0'>text</option><option value='571'>text</option><option value='591'>text</option></select>";
 $('body').append(select);
};
```

```css
    select {
    width: 100%;
    height: 35px;
    }
 .place{
  padding: 10px 15px 0 15px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select><option value="0">text</option><option value="571">text</option><option value="591">text</option></select>
```

CSS:

```
select {
width: 100%;
height: 35px;
}
.place{
    padding: 10px 15px 0 15px;
}
```

Comment: ясно, значит без дополнительного дива селекту нельзя добавить отступы. и кстати в вашем коде пропущен закрывающий тег

Comment: Спасибо. При вставке кода не увидел. На fiddle компилируеться без проблем. :)

Answer (score 2):

Пробовали исправить `margin-top: 10px 15px 0 15px;` на `margin: 10px 15px 0 15px;`?

```css
select {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 35px;
    margin: 10px 15px 0 15px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<select><option value="0">text</option><option value="571">text</option><option value="591">text</option></select>
```

Comment: прошу прощения, в вопросе ошиблась. у меня в стилях правильно указано, но не работает

Comment: Тогда, я так понимаю, проблема в том, что он не влазит со 100% шириной (лично меня это смущает) ... или ... потому что тут, вроде, отступы работают независимо от расположения селекта.